# Website Loading Animation with Jquery

Tags: jquery, loading

How would I go about creating a jquery or css animation that would play before/while the page is being loaded? This would display before the HTML elements on the page displayed.

Comment: Did tou try somethig before asking this question?

Comment: No, as I wasn't sure where to start. I'm a beginner with Jquery, sorry if this question seemed obvious.

Comment: Then please make a research and try something before asking a question. Becausr stackoverflow is not plugin finder community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the animation untill the page loads. And as soon as the objects are loaded. Hide that thing!

Here would be the example

```
<img src="someAnimationFile.gif" alt="photo" />
```

jQuery code,

```
$(document).ready(function () { // required by jquery
   $('body').load(function () { // if body, or whatever element to be loeded
      $('img').hide(); // hide the image
   }
}
```

Then it would get it working. It would keep showing the image untill the block gets loaded.

Comment: Does .load only get called when all elements are done loading? Also, can I use it on the <HTML> tags, to detect when the entire page is done?

Comment: Yes, `load` event is triggered when element has done loading. And yes you can use it on other elements too. Use it on `body` tag to detect the entire page loading process.

Answer (score 0):

quickest way would be to hide all your content with .hide() and .show() an image. Then when all your content is done toggle the content and the image visibility.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="image"/>
    <div id="content" />
    </body>
    </html>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
//pseudocode

    image.show();
    content.hide();
    ajax call
    .successful = function () {image.hide();content.show();}
    </script>
```

Comment: How can I detect when the page is done loading?

Comment: How are you loading the content? Ajax + html, .net webform,.net mvc??

Comment: HTML. I would use the .load function in Jquery, correct?